# How to Manage CPU Usage in Oracle Database 11g using Instance Caging?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am doing a little test of the cpu utilization case, got to know that i can use Instance Caging for the same to improve my resource utilization. Can somebody let me know how to do this? i m using oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance caging is a feature in the Enterprise Edition of Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2) that simplifies the management of CPU usage in consolidation environments. By enabling Resource Manager and setting the CPU_COUNT parameter in each instance, you can limit the maximum amount of CPUs/Cores the instance can use. You have to notice three points for this.

```
1. Enabling Resource Manager
2. Setting CPU_COUNT
3. Monitoring Instance Caging
```

**1. Enabling Resource Manager**
Resource Manager has been available in the Oracle database.
Resource Manager is not enabled by default, so it must be enabled by specifying a resource plan before instance caging can take effect.

```
 SELECT plan FROM dba_rsrc_plans;

  PLAN
 ------------------------------
 DEFAULT_PLAN
 INTERNAL_QUIESCE
 INTERNAL_PLAN
 APPQOS_PLAN
 DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN
 ETL_CRITICAL_PLAN
 MIXED_WORKLOAD_PLAN
 ORA$AUTOTASK_SUB_PLAN
 ORA$AUTOTASK_HIGH_SUB_PLAN
 DSS_PLAN

 10 rows selected.
 SQL>
```

If you have no specific resource management needs within the instance, the simplest solution is to use the default plan.

```
   ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN = default_plan;
```

**2. Setting CPU_COUNT**

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET cpu_count = 2;
```

**3. Monitoring Instance Caging**

The throttling effect of Resource Manager can be displayed using the CONSUMED_CPU_TIME and CPU_WAIT_TIME columns of the following views.
The CONSUMED_CPU_TIME is the number of milliseconds of CPU time consumed by the consumer group, while the CPU_WAIT_TIME is the time waiting for CPU due to Resource Manager throttling.

```
SELECT name, consumed_cpu_time, cpu_wait_time
FROM v$rsrc_consumer_group;

ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SET LINESIZE 100
SELECT begin_time,
   consumer_group_name,
   cpu_consumed_time,
   cpu_wait_time
FROM   v$rsrcmgrmetric_history
ORDER BY begin_time;
```